# Add line below tabs in ActionBar

Tags: android-actionbar, android, ui-design

After a lot of looking here and there I am posting this problem that I am facing on SO. Basically I have an Action bar with a tabbed layout. Below is a snapshot of how it looks now :

[image]

And here is the code chunk that sets the tabs :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setTheme(R.style.Theme_example);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
}
setContentView(R.layout.landing_page);

ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.LandingPage.pager);

final ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();

bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

mTabsAdapter = new LandingPageTabsAdapter(this, viewPager);
mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Search"), Search.class, null);
mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Categories"),Categories.class, null);
mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Bookmarks"), Bookmarks.class,null);

}
```

I want to add a straight line just below the tab highlighter, which is of the same color as the tab highlighter. Something like the line in Google Playstore (green line circled in red):

[image]

Currently I am styling the Actionbar using the Android Asset Studio's [ActionBar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&backColor=E4E4E4,100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6,100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2,100&accentColor=33B5E5,100). My only reason to put the line there is to get a clean look.

Can someone suggest / advice on how I can solve this ? Thanks for stopping by and lending in your thoughts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of adding a line below your actionbar try adding a line above your viewpager in your layout. Also the play store isn't using tabs they are using the [PageTitleStrip](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.html)

Comment: +1 Thanks for the input. I just added a line using View and put it above the ViewPager. I am pretty close to what I need. There is one slight difference that I see. After putting the line it appears that the tab highlighter is on top of the line. It is not smooth like the green line in above snapshot. I can clearly see the overlap visible. Is there a way to avoid this ?

Comment: I have managed to make it smoother by reducing the layout_height for the View. Looks good now. Thanks :)